# (EXPO) expo-build-properties ignored by eas-build

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I'm on Expo SDK 44, did `npx expo install expo-build-properties` under my project directory, and added the following code in app.json:

```
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-image-picker",
    {
      "photosPermission": "This app needs to access your photos to let you share them with your friends."
    }
  ],
  [
    "expo-build-properties",
    {
      "android": {
        "compileSdkVersion": 31,
        "targetSdkVersion": 31,
        "buildToolsVersion": "31.0.0"
      },
      "ios": {
        "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
      }
    }
  ]
],
```

The app builds and runs fine, but when I upload the .aab file to the Google Play Console, I get "The current target API level of your app is 30, but the minimum target API level must be 31".

Comment: Hi, are you using a managed or bare workflow?

Comment: Has anyone got any idea what's going on here. Having same issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78027658/expo-eas-build-getting-deployment-target-error-despite-setting-it-in-app-js

Answer (score 0):

expo-build-properties does not exist in expo 44. You need to upgrade to expo 45 or higher