# Expo - EAS Build - Getting Deployment Target error, despite setting it in app.json

Tags: nfc

I'm incorporating a somewhat unsupported React Native component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@better-network/react-native-nfc-passport-reader/v/0.2.1) into an Expo app. The tool is essentially a wrapper for https://github.com/AndyQ/NFCPassportReader.

On building (with Expo managed workflow), I'm getting this message:

```
'NFCPassportReader
    |        ^ compiling for iOS 13.4, but module 'NFCPassportReader' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 14.0'
```

[image: Error in EAS Build] on building despite including the following in app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 33,
            "targetSdkVersion": 33,
            "buildToolsVersion": "33.0.0"
          },
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "14.0"
          }
        }
      ],...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried reinstalling Expo build properties. I've tried npx expo prebuild --clean. I've tried cd ios && pod install. No improvement.